# How to add edges dynamically to clusters in vis.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, chap-links-library, vis.js

I am trying to add dynamic nodes to the graph created by vis.js. I can successfully add nodes and edges to an existing graph but I am looking to involve clusters now. I can create clusters for the initial graph but when the graph is modified, it adds edges (with no destination) to the existing graph. (if the destination nodes were in the cluster). On opening the cluster, the graph seems fine. Is there anyway I can create an edge to the cluster if a node is inside the cluster dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the network modular of vis, did you also make an issue on git? I'll guess so due to the similarity:

https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/930

In short, no it's not possible yet. More information on the git issue.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes. That's me. Thanks for the prompt reply. I was going through the cluster by zoom example (http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/clusteringByZoom.html) hosted on vis website to try an alternative. I edited the example to allow keyboard controls for zoom. I can zoom now but the graph does not change. I cannot see any clustering being done there. Is there something that I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: The zoom event doesn't fire on keyboard shortcuts at the moment. since that example uses that event, nothing happens. Could you make an issue on this on git? We prefer to use that. I don't want to go too much off topic here.